# Java (TM) Platform SE binary still running on processes

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, windows-task-scheduler

I created a console application using Java, then exported it as runnable JAR file. but when I run the JAR file the automation is finished but the *"Java (TM) Platform SE binary"* is still on background, I tried to put `System.exit(0)` and still not able to terminate the process.

I'm also trying to run this automatically in Task Scheduler in indefinitely repetition every 15 minutes, the problem is it will not run again after 15 minutes since the *"Java (TM) Platform SE binary"* is still in process and identified its status as running.

I'm pretty sure that all my automation task is all finished without error and not creating another threads.

**Here is my code below:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jarName = new File(Selenium.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath())
        .getName();
    System.out.println("Running " + jarName + " Automation");
    if (args.length >= 1 && args[0].toLowerCase().equals("-run")) {
        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            String pram = args[i].replace(jarName + "_", "");
            if (pram.toLowerCase().equals("all")) {
                GFC.execute("Login");
                GFC.execute("SwitchIntegration");
                GFC.execute("BODActivate");
                GFC.execute("Users");
                GFC.execute("Settings");
                GFC.execute("AccountingEntityRegistration");
                GFC.execute("CustomizedData");
                GFC.execute("BOD");
                GFC.execute("BODAttributesMDM");
                GFC.execute("BODAttributesTransactional");
                GFC.execute("CMD");
                GFC.execute("CMDAttributes");
                GFC.execute("CMDDataEntry");
                GFC.execute("CMDActivate");
                GFC.execute("AccountingEntity");
                GFC.execute("AccountingEntityMapping");
                GFC.execute("JETemplates");
                GFC.execute("Scenarios");
                GFC.execute("Rules");
                GFC.execute("RulesScript").quit();
            } else {
                if (!pram.equals("Login")) {
                    GFC.execute("Login");
                }
                GFC.execute(pram).quit();
            }
        }

        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(infor.automation.utils.Properties.get("gfc.enableemailer"))) {
            sendEmail();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** 3/14/2018

- Worrying might my automation is creating another threads, so I decide
  to create a new project and just a main class and export it as a
  runnable Jar file, and it's still the same.
- My JDK version is 1.8

Comment: Could the there be another thread running in jvm after yours ends? Are you properly shutting down selenium?

Comment: @HSchmale Do you mean the WebDriver? if that's so, I already verified it, but there's no chromedriver.exe or any related driver on the process.

Comment: @LeonelSarmiento I would assume another thread is running in the jvm as well. Try using JStack to figure out what threads are running inside the JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a workaround or maybe a solution. I found out that the `System.exit(0)` on main will only close the console application, but the *"Java (TM) Platform SE binary"* will remain. To terminate this I extended to `JFrame` class to be able to override the `ExitApp()`. Inside the `ExitApp()` I add window listener and in `windowClosing()` I called the `disposed()` and `System.exit(0)` once more. I don't have any idea how this even works. If someone know how this works feel free to update this answer.

```
public class TestClass extends JFrame {

    public void ExitApp() {
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                // Dispose Java (TM) Platform SE binary.
                dispose();
                // Close the Java.exe I'm not sure.
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Close Your Application Trigger ExitApp();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```